# Regular Expression Issue - cat

Tags: regex, perl

Given an input file that looks like this:

```
>Scaffold1
AACTGTGCCTATTTGGGCATCCGTCAGGAAAATATTGTCGCCCTCGGTGCATAAACCCATCGGCTGACCAAAGGCTGCAAAGCTGCCAGAACCGTTCCTGTTTCCTTCTTCTCCGGTACCAGCAATGACTGTAACAGTGCCGTTTCTGTCAAGGTGCATTACTTGACGCCTTGTCTGGTCGGTGAAAGCTACTTTCCCGTCTGAAAGTGGGGCAACTGCCTGTATACCGGAACTTGCTTGCCCTGCATCAGCCATGGCGTACTCTTTCACCTCCTGATTTGTTATTTTGACTTTGGTGATGCCTTTGTTGTGTGCCATAACAAGATATCCATCGGTAGATAAGCACATGCTTCGAACCTTACCTCATAGCGGTGTAAAATCACAAAACTTAGTGACTGTT
>Scaffold2
CTTTATAGAGTTTATCGATATCATGGCCGTACAAAGAAGCGCTTAATTTCTAAGGTCATCTTAGAAGCTTCGTAAACACACATTAATGTTAATGAGCTTCCTCGCCTGACAGCATCCTCGCTGCAGGACCCAACAGTGGAGGGGAAGCGGCACAGACCTTGAGGTATGGGTGCGTATGGGTGCACAATGACCTAATACGTGAATATTGATCAAATTCTAAAAAGTTACCATGAATTGAGTGTTTATTCGTATAGGGTGTTTCCTCTCAAACACGGCACCGTTATAAAACAAACAATTTCAGTTCAAATAGTTAAAAAGC
>Scaffold3
TGTTGCTTTTTCTCCTTGGTGGATGCTGCAGTTACAGACTTTCTTTTCCGGCAACAATTTAAATAATGTTCTGTGGAAAAAACGACATGTAATTATTTTGATTCGAGGTCAAACGTTGACCCAGTATTTAGTCCAGTATGACTAATTATCAATACTTTAACAAATTTACGTCATTTCTTCATGCGTCTGTCCTGTTATTGTTCATGAATTTCGTCAAAACATTGTCCGCAGACTGCTTG
```

I desire output that looks like this:

```
Scaffold1        isogroup1
AACTGTGCCTATTTGGGCATCCGTCAGGAAAATATTGTCGCCCTCGGTGCATAAACCCATCGGCTGACCAAAGGCTGCAAAGCTGCCAGAACCGTTCCTGTTTCCTTCTTCTCCGGTACCAGCAATGACTGTAACAGTGCCGTTTCTGTCAAGGTGCATTACTTGACGCCTTGTCTGGTCGGTGAAAGCTACTTTCCCGTCTGAAAGTGGGGCAACTGCCTGTATACCGGAACTTGCTTG
Scaffold2        isogroup2
CTTTATAGAGTTTATCGATATCATGGCCGTACAAAGAAGCGCTTAATTTCTAAGGTCATCTTAGAAGCTTCGTAAACAACACATTAATGTTAATGAGCTTCCTCGCCTGACAGCATCCTCGCTGCAGGACCCAACAGTGGAGGGGAAGCGGCACAGACCTTGAGGTATGGGTGCGTATGGGTGCACAATGACCTAATACGTGAATATTGATCAAATTCTAAAAAGTTACCATGAATTGAGTGTTTATTCGTATAGGGTGTTTCCTCTCAAACACGGCACCGTTATAAAACAAACAATTTCAGTTCAAATAGTTAAAAAGC
Scaffold3        isogroup3
TGTTGCTTTTTCTCCTTGGTGGATGCTGCAGTTACAGACTTTCTTTTCCGGCAACAATTTAAATAATGTTCTGTGGAAAAAACGACATGTAATTATTTTGATTCGAGGTCAAACGTTGACCCAGTATTTAGTCCAGTATGACTAATTATCAATACTTTAACAAATTTACGTCATTTCTTCATGCGTCTGTCCTGTTATTGTTCATGAATTTCGTCAAAACATTGTCCGCAGACTGCTTG
```

I can't quite seem to figure out the regular expression to make this work.

1st I tried:

```
cat test.fasta | perl -pe  's/>Scaffold(\.*).+/Scaffold$1$2\tisogroup$1/' >transcriptome_seq2iso.tab
```

But this just outputs:

```
Scaffold        isogroup
AACTGTGCCTATTTGGGCATCCGTCAGGAAAATATTGTCGCCCTCGGTGCATAAACCCATCGGCTGACCAAAGGCTGCAAAGCTGCCAGAACCGTTCCTGTTTCCTTCTTCTCCGGTACCAGCAATGACTGTAACAGTGCCGTTTCTGTCAAGGTGCATTACTTGACGCCTTGTCTGGTCGGTGAAAGCTACTTTCCCGTCTGAAAGTGGGGCAACTGCCTGTATACCGGAACTTGCTTGCCCTGCATCAGCCATGGCGTACTCTTTCACCTCCTGATTTGTTATTTTGACTTTGGTGATGCCTTTGTTGTGTGCCATAA
Scaffold        isogroup
CTTTATAGAGTTTATCGATATCATGGCCGTACAAAGAAGCGCTTAATTTCTAAGGTCATCTTAGAAGCTTCGTAAACACACATTAATGTTAATGAGCTTCCTCGCCTGACAGCATCCTCGCTGCAGGACCCAACAGTGGAGGGGAAGCGGCACAGACCTTGAGGTATGGGTGCGTATGGGTGCACAATGACCTAATACGTGAATATTGATCAAATTCTAAAAAGTTACCATGAATTGAGTGTTTATTCGTATAGGGTGTTTCCTCTCAAACACGGCACCGTTATAAAACAAACAATTTCAGTTCAAATAGTTAAAAAGC
Scaffold        isogroup
TGTTGCTTTTTCTCCTTGGTGGATGCTGCAGTTACAGACTTTCTTTTCCGGCAACAATTTAAATAATGTTCTGTGGAAAAAACGACATGTAATTATTTTGATTCGAGGTCAAACGTTGACCCAGTATTTAGTCCAGTATGACTAATTATCAATACTTTAACAAATTTACGTCATTTCTTCATGCGTCTGTCCTGTTATTGTTCATGAATTTCGTCAAAACATTGTCCGCAGACTGCTTG
```

Next I thought I could use `(\d+)` in the place of `(\.*)` as character `\d` can be used in place of any digit from 0 to 9. The `+` means one or more repitions.  However the output looks like:

```
>Scaffold1
AACTGTGCCTATTTGGGCATCCGTCAGGAAAATATTGTCGCCCTCGGTGCATAAACCCATCGGCTGACCAAAGGCTGCAAAGCTGCCAGAACCGTTCCTGTTTCCTTCTTCTCCGGTACCAGCAATGACTGTAACAGTGCCGTTTCTGTCAAGGTGCTTACTTGACGCCTTGTCTGGTCGGTGAAAGCTACTTTCCCGTCTGAAAGTGGGGCAACTGCCTGTATACCGGAACTTGCTG
>Scaffold2
CTTTATAGAGTTTATCGATATCATGGCCGTACAAAGAAGCGCTTAATTTCTAAGGTCATCTTAGAAGCTTCGTAAACACACATTAATGTTAATGAGCTTCCTCGCCTGACAGCATCCTCGCTGCAGGACCCAACAGTGGAGGGGAAGCGGCACAGACCTTGAGGTATGGGTGCGTATGGGTGCACAATGACCTAATACGTGAATATTGATCAAATTCTAAAAAGTTACCATGAATTGAGTGTTTATTCGTATAGGGTGTTTCCTCTCAAACACGGCACCGTTATAAAACAAACAATTTCAGTTCAAATAGTTAAAAAGC
>Scaffold3
TGTTGCTTTTTCTCCTTGGTGGATGCTGCAGTTACAGACTTTCTTTTCCGGCAACAATTTAAATAATGTTCTGTGGAAAAAACGACATGTAATTATTTTGATTCGAGGTCAAACGTTGACCCAGTATTTAGTCCAGTATGACTAATTATCAATACTTTAACAAATTTACGTCATTTCTTCATGCGTCTGTCCTGTTATTGTTCATGAATTTCGTCAAAACATTGTCCGCAGACTGCTTG
```

Can anyone suggest why this is not working and what a work around would be?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `\.` only matches a period (`.`). You want to use it unescaped. `\d+` would also be fine.

The second problem is that the `.+` is forcing the `.*` to match one less character than it would otherwise. Get rid of it.

```
perl -pe's/^>Scaffold(.*)/Scaffold$1\tisogroup$1/' test.fasta >output.tab
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ikegami! Your answer works great. 

So just to be clear, the `(.*)` captures as many character in the ASCII table following `Scaffold`. My _error_ was including the `.+` after if as this works sort of like a **subtraction**?

Comment: `.+` means match one or more of any character. The regex is invalid if it can't, so it backtracks a bit - takes one character from the load matched by the `.*` and lets `.+` match it instead.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand that in greater depth. I really appreciate it.